# Javascript Code on Order Object in Create Order Custom Button

Tags: javascript, button, custom

I want to override Standard Button with Custom Functionality.
When user clicks Create Order button it should check for its related Quote's Quote lines product name which contains QSM then it should alert user to replace it with other product else it should work as standard functionality.

No idea how to achieve this but it can be done by Javascript.
Please kindly guide me how to achieve this in Salesforce.

Comment: I suggest do not use JavaScript as moving forward in Lightning, You may need to do rework. Start doing it as Lightning Component button. If you are doing it for classic, then go for Visualforce page button.

Comment: Okay but need some help on this.

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what you have tried and where did you get stuck?